# How to open an application normaly without sudo command

Tags: firefox, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

i'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I've installed stardict & firefox but when i clicked at the icon the app does not responding. I only open app via terminal with $sudo firefox or $sudo stardict and the firefox browser start with administrator account (not my personal account). I've tried to re-install them but the error still appear. Please help me !

Comment: what happens if you run `firefox` command without `sudo` from terminal?

Comment: @kuket15 When i run firefox without sudo command ( click on the firefox icon) it does not respone anything, the firefox does not start.

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue in this thread http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1178332

Check if `sudo chown -R <user_name>:<user_name> ~/.mozilla` resolves your problem.